# What tripod-ready camera sling-type strap is suitable for rangefinder cameras with two side lugs?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-protection, accessories, rangefinder, camera-straps

I want to buy straps for a couple cameras, and I'm having trouble finding one that fits my needs.

1. I would prefer a sling type strap across my shoulders, with a sliding component that allows for quick access.
2. I want to be able to have my tripod mount accessible. (So products like the C-loop wouldn't work)

The cameras I want straps for are:

- Canonet QL17 GIII (film rangefinder) [photo](http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3154/3001686171_99f38c8d31.jpg)
- Olympus 35 DC (film rangefinder) [photo](http://www.olympus-global.com/en/corc/history/image-archives/camera/popup/image/pop_ee_35dc.jpg)
- Ricoh GRD III (digital compact) [photo](http://i55.tinypic.com/2ent3es.jpg) (doesn't have metal side lugs like the rangefinders, but still has one on each side instead of one like other compacts.

The only thing I could find is gordy's [sling strap](http://www.gordyscamerastraps.com/neck-sling/index.htm), with 4 different connector types, leaving the tripod mount available for mounting to a tripod.

But I want more options. I know there are plates that go on the tripod mount of a dslr camera, creating an extra tripod mount and even an extra mounting point for hands straps, but don't think these are small enough to go on the cameras I've listed above.

Comment: Nice cameras! For my Cannonet I actually use an old strap from a Canon G9 that I had. Works pretty well.

Comment: Haha, thanks! They are all really lovely cameras... that's why I want to make sure they are safe! I also use a normal neck strap for my Canonet right now, but want a sling type.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [BosStrap](http://www.bosstrap.com). It attaches to one of the side eyelets. So your tripod mount stays free.

Comment: Thanks Itai for recommending the BosStrap! I think I might get the bostail. But I'll look around longer just to make sure I get what I need. Thanks again!